# Python Google Classroom Api (Announcement.list()) method?

Tags: python, list, typeerror, google-classroom

So, I want to get the list of most recent announcements that my teacher has made on google classroom for his course.

Whenever I try to run it I keep getting this error:

[image: TypeError]

Here is my code:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from fetch import Fetch


get_credit = Fetch()
credit = get_credit() #my credentials

service = build('classroom', 'v1', credentials=credit)
get_data = service.courses()
soup = get_data.list().execute()

data = soup['courses']

name_course = [name['name'] for name in data] #name of the course
course_id = [id['id'] for id in data] #course ID

announcement = get_data.announcements()
announcement_data = announcement.list(course_id[0], page_token=10).execute()
print(announcement_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not providing the `courseId` parameter correctly:

```
announcement_data = announcement.list(course_id[0], page_token=10).execute()
```

It should be like this instead:

```
announcement_data = announcement.list(courseId=course_id[0], page_token=10).execute()
```

#### Reference:

- [announcements.list()](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/classroom/v1/python/latest/classroom_v1.courses.announcements.html#list)